# SQLAlchemy "WITH ORDINALITY"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to translate the following query with SQLAlchemy but I don't find anything on this topic in the doc.

```
SELECT * FROM table_persons, jsonb_array_elements(data->'persons') WITH ORDINALITY as persons (data, n);
```

Where the data column has JSONB type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update as of July 2021**

SQLAlchemy 1.4 introduced [table-valued functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#tutorial-functions-table-valued), supporting `WITH ORDINALITY`.

For the example in the question:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    table_persons
,   jsonb_array_elements(data->'persons') WITH ORDINALITY AS persons (data, n)
```

The corresponding SQLAlchemy code would be

```py
person_elements = (
    func.jsonb_array_elements(table_persons.c.data["persons"])
    .table_valued("data", with_ordinality="n", name="persons")
    .render_derived()
)
query = select(table_persons, person_elements)
```

The call to [`render_derived`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableValuedAlias.render_derived) is to list the individual column names in the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately support for this feature has been moved to 1.5 milestone only.
Although there is [a workaround](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3566#issuecomment-441931333), I decided to use a raw SQL to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, this workaround is the only way I found to do it.